# Magento REST API Example Errors

Tags: magento-1.9, php, api, rest-api

I'm trying to get a Magento REST API example working (Create a simple product as an Admin user with OAuth authentication) from the following link:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html

However I am receiving the following errors:

[image]

It's taken me quite some time to get this far after having to work out how to install OAuth and this part is becoming quite painful as I cannot find any solutions for these errors.

Does anybody have any ideas at all? My code is below if required:

```
<?php
$callbackUrl = "http://localhost/API.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "https://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'https://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'https://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'https://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/api/rest';
$consumerKey = '526ced0202719d14951e1849016d6b3d';
$consumerSecret = 'a06606b73962a0efbafea32af3d89380';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $productData = json_encode(array(
            'type_id'           => 'simple',
            'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
            'sku'               => 'simple' . uniqid(),
            'weight'            => 1,
            'status'            => 1,
            'visibility'        => 4,
            'name'              => 'Simple Product',
            'description'       => 'Simple Description',
            'short_description' => 'Simple Short Description',
            'price'             => 99.95,
            'tax_class_id'      => 0,
        ));
        $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $productData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
        print_r($oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo());
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certificate issue is fixed with adding `$oauth->disableSSLChecks()` to the PHP script.

State issue is fixed with adding `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` to the PHP script.